# Mondodb what is the best way to retrieve a subdocument by Id, If I know parent id and sub id

Tags: mongodb, subdocument

Now I'm doing it like so

```
Client.findOne({_id: client_id}, function (err, client) {

        if(err){ return next() }

        var phone = client.phones.filter(function (phone) {
             return phone._id === phone_id;
        }).pop();

        res.status(200).send(phone);
});
```

,but not sure if that the right way of doing it. My schema is like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("560b05b6fd9d267f60b7bb28"),
    "email" : "email@email.com",
    "__v" : 1,
    "phones" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("561a22cbe6ebf6d62965b4bc"),
            "phone" : "1234"
        }
    ]
}
```

So I would like to get phone 1234 by 560b05b6fd9d267f60b7bb28 and 561a22cbe6ebf6d62965b4bc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subdocument can't have an `_id`, at least not with the same semantics. A document's `_id` is *always* indexed and has to be unique and has some other implications. The `_id` field in the `phones` array of your documents is a normal field as `phone`.

So you can access it the usual way. In shell terms:

```
var doc = db.phones.findOne(
  // query part
  {
    "_id": knownIdOfDocument,
    "phones": $elemMatch:{"_id": knownIdOfSubdocument}
  },
  // projection
  { "phones.$":1 }
)
var phone = doc['phones'][0]; // Iirc, my JS is a bit rusty.
```